# Give a formal proof that the $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 = +\infty$

Tags: limits

Another problem troubling me is this:

Give a formal proof that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 = +\infty$$

How would I write a formal proof given this definition:

For a sequence $(S_n)$, we write $\displaystyle \lim S_n = +\infty$ provided for each $M > 0$ there is a number N such that $n > N$ implies $S_n > M$.

Comment: So on that definition, there is obviously an $N$, namely $M$ itself!

Answer (score 1):

In your case $S_{n} = n^2$. So given any $M$, just choose any $N > M$. Then for all $n \geq N$ you have $S_{n} = n^2 > n \geq N > M$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n=n^2$. Choose any $M>0$.

For this $M$ we can choose $N>\sqrt{M}$. Then for $n>N$ you have $n^2>M$, so $S_n>M$.